# Why am I getting downvoted when I downvote someone

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I downvoted an answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361658/unknown-server-tag-aspentitydatasource/12806282#12806282) and I got downvoted myself. Could somebody explain please?

[image]

Comment: You've been around for 2 years and just downvoted for the first time today?

Comment: [downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  But having said that, yeah.  People just probably expected an experienced user to have checked the FAQ first.

Comment: @Servy - If I don't downvote someone - does that mean I am not contributing to SO?

Comment: @AshishGupta No, but downvoting is one way of contributing, and it is often an important way of contributing.  Not doing so doesn't mean you aren't contributing in other ways (you clearly are) but undoubtedly you are seeing lots and lots of downvote worthy content (there's no way you could have asked and answered that many questions without seeing *any* poor or incorrect answers).  Downvoting poor or incorrect answers is helpful as it helps to inform other readers to not trust (or think twice about) that answer.

Comment: @servy Thanks . I get the point now. I just used to provide comments. I downvoted this one because It was a question itself rather than an answer. Will keep this in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: @AshishGupta That particular answer is actually a violation of the rules, rather than just being wrong.  You should flag it as "not an answer" so it can be deleted by a mod.  (You can downvote too if you want, but it won't matter once it's deleted.)  While commenting on incorrect answers is good, when it is truely wrong, or in some way harmful, you really should downvote it (in addition to commenting).

Comment: This is fast - somebody just did that to that answer, that answer got removed.

Comment: @AshishGupta Meta SO is viewed a lot by a lot of mods.  Posting content such as this that violates the rules tends to be resolved quite quickly.  Even if you hadn't posted it here on meta, if you had flagged it I've found that these simple cases take very little time to be resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not getting downvoted.

When you downvote an answer, you lose one reputation point. This is explained in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

[image: minus one to voter]

Comment: I just downvoted the answer and commented on it so that the answerer understands the reason for downvote. Didn't answer myself. Is my comment taken as an answer?

Comment: @AshishGupta - No. Your downvote on the answer by someone else causes you to lose one reputation.

Answer (score 4):

The reputation loss is *because* you downvoted, not because you *were* downvoted.

See [the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) for more information.